# How does swagger auto generate Model class documentation?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I try to find documentation on how swagger generates the model/dto class documentation. I thought it scans the classpath and reads the class attributes but then I found the following:

A class has two attributes

```
public class A {
public String var1;
public String var2;

public String setTestVar1(String var1){
     this.var1 = var1;
  }
}
```

In my swagger ui, the class is represented with three variables: var1, var2, testVar1
I know that I just have to adapt the setter and it would work but I'm interested how swagger works in detail. Does is scan for attributes and setters that are not represented by the standard setter syntax like setVar2?

I use the following dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer- 
            v2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: If by "Swagger" you mean the `swagger-core` Java library (which is used by Springfox and Springdoc), you can examine its code on GitHub: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core

Comment: I updated my post with the dependencies I use.